# Quote Generator for a website

Tags: jquery, html

While working with a client on a health clinic website she asked me if i can include in her website an inspirational quote and make it change automatically after 24 hours.

she said she will provide me with 31 sentences and each sentence should stay 24 hours on the website.

thank you a lot

Is it possible ?

---

THANK YOU GUYS YOU HAVE PUSHED ME FURTHER AND I DID IT USING JAVA SCRIPT please check it www.mummersmile.com/quote/text.html

Comment: Of course it is possible, but you have to show some effort.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your support and motivation

Comment: See this: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Honestly, I think this would be better if it were done server-side. Also, I'm voting to close because you've shown precisely *no* effort, nor research. Nor explained where, exactly, you're stuck or what problems you're having implementing this yourself.

Comment: THANK YOU GUYS YOU HAVE PUSHED ME FURTHER AND I DID IT USING JAVA SCRIPT please check it www.mummersmile.com/quote/text.html

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you save your quotes somewhere, then inject one of them into the specific portion of the page, based on the current day of the month.

**Markup:**

```
...
<div id="quote"></div>
...
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function(){

  var quotes = [
    'some wonderful quote',
    'another wonderful quote',    
    ...
    'this world is full of wonderful quotes indeed.'
  ];

  // -1 because arrays are 0 based.  
  $('#quote').text(quotes[ new Date().getDate() -1 ]);

});
```

Comment: +1'd because it's an actual genuine (and correct) answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Create an array and a initial number

`var quotes = ['quote1', 'quote2', 'quote3', 'etc'];`

`var q = 0;`

Then, have a `setInterval` function to update every 24 hours (honestly not sure if there is a better option)

and inside it have

```
 var interval = setInterval(function(){
     if(q > 31){
         q = 0;
     }else{
         $('#quote').html(quote[q]);
         q++;
 }, 86400000);
```

86400000 is 24 hours...

This could be done some much better and easier but if you're not putting in effort then you can just use this and suffer. >:)

Comment: This counts 24h since the page is loaded, and I guess no one will stay the whole day staring at the browser : ))

Comment: Thank you a lot BeatAlex, i will do my best in finding a way and thank you for your answer i will try it and am thanks for reminding me how lazy i was lately.

Comment: Yeah @moonwave99 I know haha, hence the 'use and suffer' ;P